# Time-efficient way to find uncommon words in corpus

Tags: python-3.x, function, performance, filter

I have a corpus of the following format:

```
corpus = [['tokenized_text_1'], ['tokenized_text_2'], .... ,['tokenized_text_n']]
```

I want to remove uncommon words from it

```
def remove_uncommon_words (corpus, threshold):
    uncommon_words = []
    word_count = Counter(corpus)
    for word in word_count:
        if word_count[word] < threshold:
            uncommon_words.append(word)
        else:
            continue
    clean_corpus = []
    for doc in corpus:
        clean_corpus.append([word for word in doc if word not in uncommon_words])
    return clean_corpus
```

However, this code takes very long to execute. What can I do to perform the same task faster?

Comment: What is "very long"?  Have you profiled this to identify what is taking the most time?

Comment: I think there are better options that a list for storing `uncommon_words`.

Comment: It also looks like the function Counter also reads the document to form the dictionary  word_count.  I would use a set for uncommon_words, since it will be quicker than a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is much more succinct and potentially faster version which relies primarily on `dict` comprehensions and `set` operations, which in general are faster than `list` operations b/c they are unordered and can use hashing instead:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

def remove_uncommon_words (corpus, threshold):
    word_count = Counter(chain(*corpus))
    uncommon_words = {w:c for w,c in word_count.items() if c < threshold}
    clean_corpus = word_count.keys() - uncommon_words.keys()
    return list(uncommon_words), list(clean_corpus)
```

I think overall both are *O(n)*, where *n* is the size of your corpus, but this is inevitable because at some point you will have to check every single word. Your original code iterated through the entire corpus twice, while mine just does it once, so I believe mine would be faster by a constant factor, but overall the same time complexity.

P.S: Actually, your code didn't run before, because lists are unhashable, and since `corpus` is a list of lists, you can't do `Counter(corpus)` directly. I fixed this using `chain` - see above.

Comment: Thanks Victor, this is much faster. Apparently, my data format was differently shaped than what I wrote in my question. Your suggested approach using chain works well for the format I stated above